# Adding raster data to ArcGIS Online web scene?

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, web-scene

I would like to add a number of raster datasets to an ArcGIS Online web scene, including a LiDAR DEM, a hillshade derived from it, and some aerial photography. ArcGIS Online does not support uploading any of the most common raster formats (e.g., tif), but does support rasters formatted as kml. Using the [Layer to KML tool](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012399) in ArcMap, I converted several of the raster datasets. They upload to ArcGIS online just fine and can be viewed or added as layers in the Map Viewer (2D). However, kml is not supported as a format in the 3D Scene Viewer as pointed out by Russ below.

I have also tried publishing the layers as Tile Layer Services without much luck. The rasters appear to upload fine, are recognized as data sources and preview at the correct extent and location in Web Scenes, but completely crash ArcGIS online and never load if added as a layer. They are in WGS 1984, which should be supported in global scenes and the files are not very large.

The source files (raster layers in file geodatabase) load and display correctly in normal offline ArcGIS Pro scenes and support use as elevation surfaces. So I'm not sure where the disconnect is when adding them to the online platform.

How do I add raster data to an ArcGIS online Web Scene?

I'm open to using any format or upload method that has worked for others, especially if they enable use as elevation surfaces in Web Scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KML layers are not supported in Scene Viewer currently. You can see the supported layers here:
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/add-layers-to-scene.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_AE4815736AC64DF09958DF8E73397485

For the tile layers can you share the layer & data thats causing the issue? If you are using cached data for GCS only WGS84 is supported in global scenes and for local scenes only PCS are supported.

Comment: Thanks, Russ. It's odd that KML is not supported in scene viewer. It's a native 3D format and is supported in both 2D and 3D ArcGIS desktop applications. I double checked, and the tile layers are in WGS84. So I'm not sure why they won't load in a global scene. Edited the question with this info.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the layers that are causing the issue, as they contain proprietary data. I realize that's not very helpful...

Comment: For streaming in 3D content we are currently support those features being streamed in by scene layers. For tile layers you are using within a web scene you will want to follow the same tiling scheme of the basemap in global scenes, you will want all tile data to have the same tiling scheme and SR. B/c the Scene Viewer is a light client it cannot reproject cached layers like  tile layers, elevation layers and scene layers.